# IEnumerable<T> Access properties of T inside a function using c#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

There is a c# function which accepts a list as `IEnumerable<T>`. I want to write some linq queries inside this function, but the properties of `T` seem to be not getting.

How can we map T to a specific type before writing Linq statement? In this case it's of type `CustomerAddress` with 3 properties `Id, Name, Gender`.

```
private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SmartSplit<T>(IEnumerable<T> sourceList)
{
    // not able to access any props of T; in this case T is of type CustomerAddress
    int itemsCount = sourceList.Where(v => v.???==).Count();  
}
```

I want to fetch the `itemsCount` as the count of items with length of name > 50  inside this function. Linq for that will be  against a list is like

```
int itemsCount = sourceList.Where(p => p.Name.Length > 50).Count();
```

But how can I access the property `Name` inside the `SmartSplit` function? I can see that there is a way of doing this by casting to a list first and then write LINQ like below

```
private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SmartSplit<T>(IEnumerable<T> sourceList)
{
    List<CustomerAddress> sourceListCopy = sourceList as  List<CustomerAddress>;
    int itemsCount=  sourceListCopy.Where(p => p.Name.Length > 50).Count();
}
```

Can we do this without casting and copying to a temp list inside the function?

Comment: Well then don't make `SmartSplit` accept an `IEnumerable<T>`! Make it accept an `IEnumerable<CustomerAddress>`.

Comment: Seems like your function expexts an `IEnumerable<CustomerAdress>`, not a `IEnumerable<T>`, unless `T` is constrainted to `CustomerAdress`.

Comment: If you don't want to constrain it to `CustomerAddress`, you can use an interface that declares a `string Name` property, and make `CustomerAddress` implement that interface. With your current code, there is no way to guarantee that any type `T` will have a `Name` property

Comment: On a side note, `.Where(p => ...).Count()` can be rewritten `.Count(p => ...)`

Comment: If you don't want to specify a type or interface instead of a generic, then you could pass in the `Where` clause as a parameter too.

Comment: Not sure Why so many downvotes, Is this is a platform to clear doubts and learn unknown things as well?

Comment: Do you need it to be  `T`, why not `CustomerAddress`?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pass there not only CustomerAddress you should extract your common property to interface and after that use constraint with 'where' clause. 
Example:

```
  public interface ICustomerInfo
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SmartSplit<T>(IEnumerable<T> sourceList) where T: ICustomerInfo, class
    {
        int itemsCount = sourceList.Where(v => v.Name.Length > 50).Count();
        return default;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you propose using a constraint instead of `IEnumerable<ICustomerInfo>`?

Comment: So, in your case method always should return interface. In case if you don't need that, with constraint you can return exact type as you pass inside.
For example:

`IEnumerable<CustomerInfo> split = SmartSplit(new List<CustomerInfo>());` <br>
`IEnumerable<SuperCustomerInfo> split1 = SmartSplit(new List<SuperCustomerInfo>());`

With interface: 
`IEnumerable<ICustomerInfo> split = SmartSplit(new List<CustomerInfo>());` <br>
`IEnumerable<ICustomerInfo> split1 = SmartSplit(new List<SuperCustomerInfo>());`